# Create a simple registration system using only HTML and MySql

Tags: mysql, html, css

Is it possible to create a simple registration system with HTML,CSS and MySql without using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML, and CSS would typically generate client content while MySql is in most cases quite server specific. php is most of the time used as a server-side language.

So what actually is happening when you for example post from a form in your html it will generate a request sent to the server where it is evaluated and a response is likely.

So in HTML you would typically set up your form and tell it an action to take (a script on the server to run), this server-script could typically be written in any language, but let's keep on topic and assume the server script is in php. (example of other popular server-side scripts would be ruby on rails, python, lua to name a few).

How it is typically used then is for php to do the query on the database and all of this is on the server and the client know nothing at all about it. A result is generated and returned to the client if it should do so.

So no, it is not possible to use client-side to access a database on the server, if I interpret the question correctly. Hope it helps to clarify the concepts somewhat.

Comment: nice explaination. +1

Comment: @JasonKw glad if it helps, it's a bit difficult to make the abstraction without going into a lot of details. But basically I believe that knowing the difference in things the server do and things  the client does is the key, good luck with your future endeavors.

Comment: @qrikko Can i ask 1 more question?What is the function of Wamp Server?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do with only html and sql. You will require php in order to connect to database.

Html will be used to display values coming from database. Css can be used for styling elements on page.